# Having an error while logging or signing up a User

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

**Problem:** I've been trying to get the User's signup and login info saved into my database and then redirect the user to another page using *useNavigate* Hook. But whenever I click on the signup button OR login button (in frontend), it fails and occurs a problem in the console. The API's for the login and signup in backend are working fine using the Postman, but I will still share its backend downside.
I am unable to find the error in my code.

**Image Of Error:** [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz1gL.png). This is the error I am getting in my console whenever I click to login or signup on website.

**NOTE**: I used "http://localhost:5000" server in backend and "http://localhost:3000" server for the frontend and starting both server using the 'concurrently' npm package. Highlighting this info because I saw somewhere that this URL could be the reason of my error. Please do tell if it is an issue of URL, and also the solution please!

I'll share the express and react files down here:

**auth.js** file (backend):

```
 // Route:1 Create a new user , POST: /api/auth/createuser
   router.post('api/auth/createuser' , [
   body("name" , "Please enter a valid name").exists(),
   body("email" , "Please enter valid credentials").isEmail(),
   body("password" , "Please enter valid credentials").isLength({min: 5})
   ], async (req, res)=>{
    let success= false;
   const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     return res.status(400).json({success, errors: errors.array() });
   }
      try {
        let user = await userDB.findOne({email: req.body.email});
     if(user){
        return res.status(400).json(success, "Sorry, A user with this email already exists.")
     }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password , salt);

user = await userDB.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  email:req.body.email,
  password: password,
})
const data = {
    user: {
        id: user.id
    }
}
const authToken = jwt.sign(data , JWT_SECRET);
res.json({success: true, authToken})
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error Occurred")
  }
 },
 );

 // Route:2 Login an existing user , POST: /api/auth/loginuser
 router.post('/loginuser', [
   body("email", "Please enter valid credentials").isEmail(),
   body("password", "Please enter valid credentials").isLength({min: 5})
   ], async (req, res)=>{
   let success = false;
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
   return res.status(400).json({success , errors: errors.array() });
   }
   const {email, password} = req.body
    try {
    let user = await userDB.findOne({email})
    if(!user){
    res.status(400).send("Please enter correct credentials")
    }
    const comparePassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if(!comparePassword){
    res.status(400).send("Please enter correct credentials")
    }
    const data = {
    user: {
      id: user.id,
     },
    };
     const authToken = jwt.sign(data, JWT_SECRET);
     success= true;
     res.json({success, authToken})
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error Occurred")
   }
    });


    // Route:3 Fetch all the signed users , POST: /api/auth/fetchuser
    router.post('/fetchuser' , fetchUser, async (req,res)=>{
    try {
    userID = req.user.id
    const user = await userDB.findById(userID).select("-password")
    res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error Occurred")
    }
   })

   module.exports = router;
```

**index.js** file (backend):

```
 const express = require("express");
 const mongoConnect = require("./db/mongoConnect");
 const cors = require("cors");
 const app = express();
 const port = 5000;

 mongoConnect();
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cors());


 app.use("/api/auth" , require("./routes/auth"));
 app.use("/api/tasks" , require("./routes/tasks"));



 app.listen(port, ()=>{
 console.log(`Backend listening to ${port}` )
 })
```

**Login.js** react component file: (using *MaterialUI*)

```
  export default function Login (){
  const host = "http://localhost:3000";

  const onChange=(e)=>{
  setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
  }

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/loginuser`, {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    email: credentials.email,
    password: credentials.password,
    }),
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);

  if (json.success) {
  localStorage.setItem("token", json.authtoken);
  navigate("/");
  } else {
  console.log("Invalid Credentials");
  }
  };

return(
   <Box
          component="form"
          noValidate
          onSubmit={handleLogin}
          sx={{ mt: 1 }}
        >
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            type="email"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            onChange ={onChange}
            value={credentials.email}
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            value={credentials.password}
            onChange ={onChange}
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            sx={{
              mt: 3,
              mb: 2,
              bgcolor: "#4c3c3c",
              "&:hover": { bgcolor: "#5c3c3c" },  
            }}
          >
            Log In
          </Button> 
   ))
```

**SignUp.js** react component file: (using *MaterialUI*)

```
   export default function SignUp() {
   const host = "http://localhost:3000/"
   const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({name: "",email: "", password: ""})

   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const response = await fetch(`${host}api/auth/createuser`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
     body: JSON.stringify({
     name: credentials.name,
     email: credentials.email,
     password: credentials.password
   })
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(response)
  if(json.success){
  localStorage.setItem("token" , json.authtoken)
  navigate("/login")
  } else {
  console.log("Invalid Credentials")
 }
};

const onChange = (e) =>{
 setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
 }

 return(
  <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSignUp} sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              id="name"
              label="Username"
              onChange = {onChange}
              name="name"
              autoComplete="family-name"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              onChange = {onChange}
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              onChange = {onChange}
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="new-password"
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, bgcolor:"#4c3c3c" , "&:hover" :{bgcolor:"#5c3c3c"} }}
        >
          Sign Up
        </Button>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all probably you should send correct format json data from backend to client
for example:

```
res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error Occurred")
```

try send json everywhere:

```
res.status(500).json({message: "Internal Server Error Occurred"})
```

Also, in SignUp you should wrap to JSON.stringify instead of just save object or array in localStorage
you have `localStorage.setItem("token" , json.authtoken)`

try this `localStorage.setItem("token" , JSON.stringify(json.authtoken))`

and fix in auth.js

```
return res.status(400).json(success, "Sorry, A user with this email already exists.")
```

to this

```
return res.status(400).json({success, "Sorry, A user with this email already exists."})
```

I believe that problems will be solved after this.